# Error Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: eclipse

I am getting this error while running ivy in Eclipse.

```
---- Compiler Messages ---
info directory classpath entry does not exist: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
info zipfile classpath entry does not exist: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes
abort ABORT -- (ClassFormatException) File: 'META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
File: 'META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addAspectsFromJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:260)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:236)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:874)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.AjcTask.executeInSameVM(AjcTask.java:1286)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.AjcTask.execute(AjcTask.java:1096)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:142)
```

Comment: It looks something (maybe weaving via AspectJ) fails reading Java 9 bytecode of a [multi-release JAR file](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) instead of just ignoring everything in `META-INF/versions/` of that JAR.

Comment: any idea how can this be resolved?

Comment: If you target only Java 8, you can remove `META-INF/versions/` from this JAR. Alternatively, a newer version of the tool that does the weaving might be the solution (if not, make sure this issue have been reported to that tool).